# Is there a syntactically concise way to extract a parameter list from a list of objects in vb

Tags: vb.net, lambda

Is there a lambda expression to extract a list of a particular parameter from a list of objects in VB.Net?

```
For Each item As MyObj In MyListOfMyObj
    Label &= item.Name
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `Select` method, like this:

```
Dim names() As IEnumerable(Of String) = MyListOfMyObj.Select(Function(item) item.Name)
```

Then you can easily combine them with `String.Join`, for instance:

```
Label = String.Join(", ", names)
```

Or, if you don't need a delimiter, like in your example, then you could use `String.Concat`:

```
Label = String.Concat(names)
```

So, you can do it in one line like this:

```
Label = String.Concat(MyListOfMyObj.Select(Function(item) item.Name))
```

Whether you thing that's more concise and easier to read is a matter of preference.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to use String.Join, it was the Select I couldn't find.